# How to show the user multiple options and make sure they understand they don't have to choose one

Tags: mobile

So I am currently developing this app that shows you ads and you swipe right if interested and left if not. When thinking about how to present the ads, instead of an 'infinite scroll' I thought it would make for a better user experience to show three, let they make decisions and then advance to the next set of ads.

I want to make sure the user understands that by giving they three options it doesn't mean that you can only choose one, but you can choose all three or none of them. What are some good ways of improving my scenes in this regard?

Here's how my app looks, with some example data

[image]

(The space at the bottom is intentional, I am thinking of what to add there)

Any kind of tip is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If someone swiped to be 'interested' what happens?

Comment: @DarrylGodden a chat between whoever posted the ad and whoever swiped is created.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you think displaying 3 ads are user-friendly than an infinite scrolling?

Comment: @Gagsy from personal experience, when there is an infinite scroll there is too much information to bear. I think that by displaying 3 ads I let the user focus on those three without worrying about the others. I would love to hear what is your opinion on that. Thanks.

Comment: What's your plan if the person isn't available to chat, or are we talking more off-line messaging than 'chats?'

Comment: @DarrylGodden what I mean with chat is a chatroom between those two users is created. I assume at some time the person will be available to chat, they both don't have to be online to chat though, imagine it as a whatsapp chatroom is created between those two (maybe that is that what you mean by 'off-line messaging')? Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Levon: Personally, I would go with an endless scrolling approach instead of pagination. For example, the user would have to make 5 clicks to reach the 16th item in the list.

Your layout looks similar to Facebook or Instagram which uses an endless scrolling approach. Most of the social media users are already trained with his approach and moreover, I believe it is easier to scroll than click in a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

Create one button at the bottom that will contextually be labeled "Next ->" or "Skip These ->" depending on whether the visitor has made a selection of one or more of the three items or not.